# Draw part of texture in AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine, sprite

So i've been using ligbdx for some time, and it was really simple there to do such thing. So what i want to achieve is that when i have a large texture i would like to get a part of that texture by giving x,y (where to start cutting from) and width,height (size of cut part) and later use that part as a sprite or anything that is possible to be drawn on the andengine scene.

In libgdx it ws like that:

```
//loads file from assets into texture
Texture texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/texture5.png")); 

//cuts a part of it into drawable element
TextureRegion part = new TexureRegion(texture, x, y, width, height);
```

and part was just that section of the texture i needed to draw later on the screen. Is it really so hard to do in andengine that nowwhere on the internet i couldnt find any answer for 2h of searching? :)

Answer (score 0):

I have just searched for hours and got nothing. But accidentally i tried this, and it worked. It's an old question but whatever. Maybe this can help.

```
    ITexture texture = null;
    try {
        texture = new BitmapTexture(engine.getTextureManager(),
                new IInputStreamOpener() {

                    public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                        return engine.getAssets().open(path);
                    }
                });

        texture.load();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ITextureRegion texturePart = new TextureRegion(texture, x, y, width, height);
```